# Which namespace do i use for laravel view()?

Tags: laravel

My ide typhints a few different namespaces for rendering a view in my controller and i'm not sure which one i'm supposed to use:

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() : View
    {
        return view('posts.index');
    }
}
```

The "view" function returns multiple types:

```
@return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
```

1. So which one am i supposed to use? \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View or \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
2. What is the difference?
3. Why is it returning two different types instead of one? I code php in a strict way because i prefer it for readable and less error prone code, in my opinion this is a bad way of doing it and as you can see is causing confusion; a method should only be allowed one return type, create multiple methods if need be.

**EDIT**

Thank you for your input everyone, i have come up with the following that allows me to use the facade and the contract without producing typhint errors in my ide:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


    use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View as ViewContract;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View as ViewFacade;
    
    /**
     * Class PostsController
     * @package App\Http\Controllers
     */
    class PostsController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @return ViewContract
         */
        public function index() : ViewContract
        {
            return ViewFacade::make('posts.index');
        }
    }
```

So i can call View:make() and return the contract that View:make() returns.

**EDIT 2**

Using the view() helper i can condense further, i am aliasing with ViewContract just for my benefit of knowing which namespace i'm using:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View as ViewContract;


/**
 * Class PostsController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class PostsController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @return ViewContract
     */
    public function index() : ViewContract
    {
        return view('posts.index');
    }
    
}
```

Comment: However, i can use the helper view() to avoid using both namespaces, i get it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ll try and address each of your questions.

1. In your instance, type-hint `Illuminate\Contracts\View\View` or the concrete implementation (`Illuminate\View\View`).
2. I’ll cover this in 3.
3. You’re using the `view` global helper function. It can return different types because, well, it can. If you don’t pass a parameter to `view()` then it will return a view factory instance. If you *do* pass a parameter (like you have in your usage), then it will return an instance of the view named by the first parameter (if such a view exists). So that’s why the `view()` helper function is typed to return multiple different types. Because depending on how you use it, it *can* return a different type.

Comment: This explains what i wanted to know in point 3, thanks! So as sta said i think for me my best approach is to use View:make() as that makes more sense to me than using the helper function that confuses things.

Answer (score 1):

You mean: `\Illuminate\View\View`.

```php
    public function index(): \Illuminate\View\View
    {
        return view('posts.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[view()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-view) is a helper of `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View` facade.

```
return view('posts.index');
```

Same as :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

return View::make('posts.index');
```

See the documentation of [Creating & Rendering Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views)

Comment: Thank you for your input on this part, i will be using View::make() from now on as it makes more sense to me to do so.

Comment: I've updated my post with my solution based on everyone's answers.